# UICollectionViewCell change background color for multiple cells

Tags: xcode, swift

I want to change the cell background color of the selected cell but anytime i select a cell it changes the background color of the selected cell and another random cell. What could be wrong?

Here is my code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    return cell
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    let cell = colorCollection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, don't you actually want to set the cell's background color and not the content view's? I think it should be like this:

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
```

Then you can just go with setting the color of the selected background view like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    let selectionView = UIView()
    selectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionView

    return cell
}
```